# Docker Hub: Repository Links for Automated Builds

Tags: docker, dockerhub

In [Docker Hub](http://hub.docker.com/) one can configure [Automated Builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) by clicking on the corresponding button in the upper-right corner of the `Builds` tab. Apart from configuring a rebuild on pushing to the source-code repository containing the `Dockerfile`, one can also set "*Repository Links*" to "*Enable for Base Image*". This is intended to "*Trigger a build in this repository whenever the base image is updated on Docker Hub*".

I got this to work in some simple toy-example cases. But it fails to trigger on a more complex example. My `Dockerfile` looks something like this:

```
FROM mediawiki AS orig

FROM alpine AS build
COPY --from=orig <file> /
RUN <patch-command of file>

FROM mediawiki
COPY --from=build <file> /
```

Why does the rebuild not trigger if (either of) the base-images gets updated? Is this because I have more than one `FROM` line in the `Dockerfile`? Or did the warning "*Only works for non-official images*" apply to the base image instead of the destination image?

If the answer to my last question above is "yes", is there some way to still get the desired effect of rebuilding on base image updates?

Answer (score 3):

> "Only works for non-official images"

I'm fairly sure it doesn't work for any official images like `alpine`, `golang`, etc. The reason is that so many images depend on those base images that a single update would be a huge burden on their infrastructure to rebuild everyone's images.

My guess is that the logic to determine whether an image uses an official image or not is very basic and if it detects `FROM <some-official-image>` *anywhere* in your Dockerfile then it probably won't get automatically rebuilt.

Comment: I will interpret this answer as "the warning does mean the base image, not the destination image" with some nice reasoning as to why. Any idea how to get around it? Tons of people must have this problem...

Comment: For my projects I don't build on Docker Hub. I build using CircleCI or the new GitHub Actions and then push to Docker Hub. To make sure base images get updated regularly I use renovatebot. When it finds an update it sends a PR. You merge the PR and release a new version of your image.
https://renovatebot.com/

Comment: Here is an example renovatebot PR that it sent to one of my images.
https://github.com/peter-evans/liche-docker/pull/6